# How to initialize the variables of domain class with the properties defined in config.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I have defined a variable in Config.groovy as below

```
environments {
    development {
        training.defaultStartTime = "09:00"

    }
    production {
        training.defaultStartTime = "09:00"
    }
}
```

Now **I want to Initialize the variable startTime  in my domain class using grailsApplication.config .defaultStartTime** . I am doing as follows

```
class Training {
    def grailsApplication
    String startTime = grailsApplication.config.training.defaultStartTime
}
```

But getting an error

> *"Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception
>   is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test
>   objectcom.Training"*

**what is the best way to initialize the variables of domain class with the properties defined in config.groovy (grailsapplication)**

Comment: How to use config.groovy properties to initialize the variables of a domain class

Comment: We cant use grailsapplication as it mentioned "Implementors of this inteface should be aware that a GrailsApplication is only initialised when the initialise() method is called. In other words GrailsApplication instances are lazily initialised by the Grails runtime."

Answer (score 4):

The problem is due to the way injection works. The bean (in the case a domain class instance) is created using its default constructor, then the DI fields are set to the corresponding beans. But the `startTime` field is initialized in the constructor - before DI happens - so `grailsApplication` is null.

One workaround would be to create a custom constructor - see http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1003 for the details

Comment: Event this solution is not working except the ConfigurationHolder

Comment: I have seen that  we cant use grailsapplication.config.myproperty to initialize the variables of a class but can be accessed inside methods

Comment: According to  http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html GrailsApplication is only initialised when the initialise() method is called. In other words GrailsApplication instances are lazily initialised by the Grails runtime